# Is there a way to get autocompletion and auto import working with Sublime Ensime plug-in in Sublime Text 2 for Play! projects

Tags: playframework, sublimetext2, sublimetext, ensime

I've been searching the entire web to get a proper ST2 configuration to work with a Play! project (version 2.1)

I finally ended up to this configuration steps (greatly inspired from http://engineering.panaxiom.co.uk/post/34631917299/sublime-text-2-with-sbt-and-play-2) :

1. Added ensime plugin in project/plugins.sbt :

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbt-cmd" % "0.1.1")
   ```
2. Generated ensime file project from play console with :

   ```
   ensime generate
   ```
3. Installed sublime-ensime package for ST2 from Package Control :Install Package
4. Installed the ensime server ensime_2.10.0-0.9.8.9 and extracted files in ST2/Packages/Ensime/server folder
5. I also installed SublimeJava plugin for basic java code support and
   play2-sublimetext2 plugin for play specific syntax highlighting and
   snippets.

With all this configuration setup, I get two critical issues for application and third party lib

- autocompletion don't work for application or third-party class, whereas SublimeJava autocompletion for native class works very well (I checked my .ensime project file and all the paths seems correctly set)
- auto imports feature barely works and display a quicklist with the right package name but when I select one, my screen blinks and no import is added. This feature works well too with SublimeJava for basic class

So there must be a way for cleaning up this, but I can't find how.... Please note that I write code in Java for Play, not Scala, but that shouldn't be a problem since it's jars paths in my .ensime file.

Thanks by advance to those who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is currently [abandoned](https://github.com/sublimescala/sublime-ensime#project-status), so unless you or someone you know wants to take over its maintenance, nothing is going to get fixed. If you check out the project's [issues](https://github.com/sublimescala/sublime-ensime/issues) page, there are currently two open issues for the features you mentioned: [autocompletion](https://github.com/sublimescala/sublime-ensime/issues/93) (from Nov. 2013) and [auto imports for Java](https://github.com/sublimescala/sublime-ensime/issues/98) (Nov. 2014). Neither one has any replies from the project devs, or anyone else, for that matter. Even the project's [website](http://www.sublimescala.org) is gone.

So, unless you can fix these issues yourself, it looks like you're out of luck. Sorry!

Comment: Guess I'll have to deal with it, if no one else seems to have a solution... Thank you for your time.